# файл удаляется, а старые данные все равно остаются

Tags: java

удалил файл, а данные остались,как так? Вот код

```
                if(content.contains("1223994251")) {
                     Path phn = java.nio.file.Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt");
                     String phn1="C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt";
                     Files.delete(phn);

                     if (!Files.exists(phn)) {System.out.println("Файл удален!");
                       Thread.sleep(3500);
                       file.delete();
                       file.createNewFile();
                       Files.write(Paths.get(phn1), content.getBytes());

                }}
                else {
                    Path phn2 = java.nio.file.Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt");
                     String phn3="C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt";
                     Files.delete(phn2);

                     if (!Files.exists(phn2)) {System.out.println("Файл удален!");
                       Thread.sleep(3500);
                       content=content+"1223994251";
                       file.delete();
                       file.createNewFile();
                       Files.write(Paths.get(phn3), content.getBytes());        
       }}

        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При удалении файла удаляется только его имя из каталога. Данные можно читать и записывать до тех пор пока есть процесс в котором этот файл открыт. При закрытии файла место под ним помечается как свободное.

Похоже тут больше уместно использовать https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate(long)

Также посмотрите на операции seek - в большинстве случаев лучше просто перезаписывать данные поверх.

Comment: тогда, как я могу отчищать данные в файле?

Comment: truncate  метод помечает место больше определенного как свободное. это то что Вам нужно.